# Unable to open navigation drawer: No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Yesterday everything was ok, but today I've started to working again in my app, in the xml file of an activity but Android Studio show nothing on the phone interface (That one that is located normally to the right, just next to the XML code.) It says that it is a render problem.
[Here you can see that the layou is displayed normally but i can't see my edits until I run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPtYs.png)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity RIGHT
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1736)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1722)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:56)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.DrawerLayoutUtil.openDrawer(DrawerLayoutUtil.java:59)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.DrawerLayoutUtil.openDrawer(DrawerLayoutUtil.java:53)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.postInflateProcess(BridgeInflater.java:577)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:702)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:707)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:338)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:373)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:713)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:844)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Note that this errors doesnt show in the logcat, because all is running except the visualizator.
It says something like there is not drawer view with gravity RIGHT, and off course there is not. But IDK why is now searching for it.

Here is my code. I have already worked with this configuration so I think this is not the problem.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_dar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    tools:openDrawer="end"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_dar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/itemBlueDark"
            app:title="Sube tu objeto"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:id="@+id/title_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Categoría"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/spinner_Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="none"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/nombre_objeto"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:background="@color/white"

            android:hint="@string/nombre_objeto">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/nombre_objeto_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/desc_objeto"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/descripcion_objeto">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/desc_objeto_editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_objeto"
            android:layout_width="274dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sin_foto" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_enviar_imagen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/forma_btn"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/itemBlueDark"
            android:text="Subir" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_listaUsuarios"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/cabecera_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[here you can see that there is a problem w/ the Layout Rendering Engine. I've tried to enable/disable it but it seems it does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCC3L.png)

[Here you can see other errors related to the rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgk8V.png)

[Althouhg other XML files have the same render issues, AndroidStudio display the desing visualizator properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXhLB.png)

EDIT: Here are my dependencies, maybe some of this are wrong, but i doubt it.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Trueque"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    //para las cajas de texto
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //Para dependencias de firebase

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Para las tabs deslizantes
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')

    // Declare the dependency for the Realtime Database library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')

    // Declare the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'

}
```

Comment: `tools:openDrawer="end"` – Your drawer is on the `start` side, not the `end`. Change that attribute value on the `<DrawerLayout>`, or just remove it.

Comment: No, it does not work. :(

Comment: Make sure to rebuild the project, so you're looking at the current version. If that doesn't work, restart Android Studio. If that doesn't either, File -> Invalidate caches/Restart.

Comment: @MikeM. I've done that 4 o 5 times. I've restarted AS several times. Clean And Rebuilded the project also a couple of times. IDK if it has to be with some implementation dependencies.

Comment: I have figured out why this happened to me. It has to be with the implementation of the Spinner, because, having tried everything, the only think that worked was deleting the spinner. IDKW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by deleting the following lines in the XML file.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_spinner"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:hint="Categoría">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/spinner_Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="none" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            tools:listitem="@layout/spinner_layout" />
```